# How to install Ubuntu to my second SSD?

Tags: system-installation, ssd

I've been searching around google and I've seen a few guides to "dual booting", but I don't want to put two operating systems on one drive.

I have a 240 GB SSD for windows and a 64 unused SSD that I want to put ubuntu on. As well as a 1TB hard drive.

Can I just unplug my 240GB SSD and my hard drive, and then install it to the 64 GB SSD?

If so, then have can I have it prompt me if I want to boot into windows or ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: Just pretend that the 64GB SSD is a USB stick and follow above answer... (The short answer being: yes, you can!)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can just unplug your windows hard drive and install it as your "only" operating system on the other drive. Follow any installation guide you want.

With both drives plugged in, you will be able to select which drive to boot from using the BIOS. It might also be possible to use GRUB, but with separate drives it would probably be more trouble than it's worth. Your BIOS should let you pick your default boot device in setup. When you want to boot your secondary boot device, most BIOSes will say something along the lines of "Press F12 to select boot device."

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me so quickly! I will look at your guide and follow it! Have a nice day. :)